# The while loop that checks the string for array elements keeps looping after correct value is entered. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: java

```
    String [] vKeywordsArray;
    int vNumberofKeywords = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many keywords do you want to enter?"));
    vKeywordsArray = new String[vNumberofKeywords];  
    int i=0;
    while (i < vNumberofKeywords)
    {
         vKeywordsArray[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your keyword to be stored in index " +i+ ".");
         i++;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for the input(s).");          
    for (int j=0; j < vKeywordsArray.length; j++)
    {
       String vKeywords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to talk about today?");
       boolean vCheck = vKeywords.contains(vKeywordsArray[j]);
       while (vCheck == false)
       { 
           vKeywords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry I did not get that, please enter one of the relevant keywords mentioned earlier.");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (vCheck == false)` <- if that loop is entered how would `vCheck` ever become true? You don't change it in the loop after all.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, that should be an answer

Comment: How can I fix this? Im so confused. Im still very new to java programming.

Comment: @smac89 I'd rather have question like this silently dissappear with 0 answers by the automatic cleanup system ;)

Answer (score 0):

in the loop

```
while( vCheck == false){
    vKeywords = jOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry I did not get that, please enter one of the relevant keywords mentioned earlier.");
}
```

you never update your vCheck condition. Since the vCheck remains false the loop will continue forever.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `while` loop you need a `if` condition actually like below. I did not find any reason for a while loop there because in the while loop you are displaying a message and for that you don't need a loop at all.

```
while (vCheck == false)
   { 
       vKeywords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry I did not get that, please enter one of the relevant keywords mentioned earlier.");
   }
```

Change it to:-

```
  if (vCheck == false)
   { 
       vKeywords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry I did not get that, please enter one of the relevant keywords mentioned earlier.");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reevaluate your boolean vCheck variable after you receive your new input from the user.

```
while (vCheck == false)
{ 
    vKeywords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry I did not get that, please enter one of the relevant keywords mentioned earlier.");
    vCheck = vKeywords.contains(vKeywordsArray[j]);
}
```